# How to skip bad dates in DBpedia SPARQL request?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I need to get data about films from DBpedia.

I use SPARQL query as follows on http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?subject ?label ?released WHERE {
  ?subject rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>.
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label.
  ?subject <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate> ?released.
  FILTER(xsd:date(?released) >= "2000-01-01"^^xsd:date).
} ORDER BY ?released
LIMIT 20
```

I tried to get films that were released after 01.01.2000.
But the engine answers as follows:

```
Virtuoso 22007 Error DT006: Cannot convert 2009-06-31 to datetime : 
Too many days (31, the month has only 30)

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?subject ?label ?released WHERE {
  ?subject rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>.
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label.
  ?subject <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate> ?released.
  FILTER(xsd:date(?released) >= "2000-01-01"^^xsd:date).
} ORDER BY ?released
LIMIT 20
```

As far as I can understand there are some errors in data in DBpedia and the engine cannot convert string data to date type in order to compare with the date I set. And the engine breaks the query execution.

So, the question is: is there any way to tell the engine to skip all the erroneous data and return to me all that could be processed?

Comment: looks like it's a bug in dbpedia

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**COALESCE**](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce) function in order to define a default date for invalid ones:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?subject ?label ?released ?released_fixed WHERE {
  ?subject rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>.
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label.
  ?subject <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate> ?released.
  bind ( coalesce(xsd:datetime(?released), '1000-01-01') as ?released_fixed)
  FILTER(xsd:date(coalesce(xsd:datetime(?released), '1000-01-01')) >= "2000-01-01"^^xsd:date).
} ORDER BY ?released
LIMIT 20
```

This query provides following [SPARQL Results on DbPedia Live Endpoint](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3a%20%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20?subject%20?label%20?released%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?subject%20rdf%3atype%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film%3E.%0D%0A%20%20?subject%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label.%0D%0A%20%20?subject%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate%3E%20?released.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%28xsd%3adate%28coalesce%28xsd%3adatetime%28?released%29,%20%271000-01-01%27%29%29%20%3E=%20%222000-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3adate%29.%0D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20?released%0D%0ALIMIT%2020&format=text/html&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The bind construct is only for presenting the fixed dates which are set to '1000-01-01' and stored in the variable *?release_fixed*. The bind is not necessary for the query and can be omitted together with *?release_fixed* in the SELECT clause

Comment: Is the bind() necessary here (if so why please)? I tried this both with and without the bind(), and still get the same error OP reported.

Comment: I have enhanced my answer in order to explain the bind().

Answer (score 1):

One way is to filter using the datatype, as you can see below:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?subject ?label ?released WHERE {
  ?subject rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>.
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label.
  ?subject <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate> ?released.
  FILTER(datatype(?released) = <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>)
  FILTER(xsd:date(?released) >= "2000-01-01"^^xsd:date).
} ORDER BY ?released
LIMIT 20
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fsubject+%3Flabel+%3Freleased+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fsubject+rdf%3Atype+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FFilm%3E.%0D%0A++%3Fsubject+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel.%0D%0A++%3Fsubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FreleaseDate%3E+%3Freleased.%0D%0A++FILTER%28datatype%28%3Freleased%29+%3D+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23dateTime%3E%29%0D%0A++FILTER%28xsd%3Adate%28%3Freleased%29+%3E%3D+%222000-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%29.%0D%0A%7D+ORDER+BY+%3Freleased%0D%0ALIMIT+20&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Trying to run that query results in an error: `Virtuoso 22023 Error SR066: Unsupported case in CONVERT (incomplete RDF box -> DATE)`.  This seems similar to the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Discarding a result with a date that is off by a day seems silly to me (like Windows doing a bugcheck whenever it feels something is wrong, eg your GPU video adaptor hanging 5 times in a row).

Since you only care about the year, isn't it better to compare string-wise?

```
str(?released) >= "2000"
```

XSD says "at least 4 digits for the year" so this works for all positive years (AD).
BTW this will also work if the DBpedia extraction framework found only a year in that field.